# Different counts of indexed pages for site: search on Google with trailing and without trailing slash

Tags: google, trailing-slash, google-site-search

I am checking my website for the indexed pages using the site command.

I am getting the following results

- `site:in.example.com` (about 23,000 results) [Without trailing slash]
- `site:in.example.com/` (about 8,000 results) [With trailing Slash]

Previously our site has enforced a trailing slash rule but now they are all redirected to without a trailing slash.

Please let me know why both version have such variations in results.